# Rest Controller works just for Application class

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-restcontroller, get-mapping

I'm trying to do a getmapping method using rest-api which will return as a JSON on localhost: 8080. When I do this from the default Application class it works great but when I move this functionality to another class nothing happens. Could someone help me with this, please?

[image: Application Class]

[image: BookController Class]

Comment: What package is `MySpringBootAppApplication` in?

Comment: Pls specify package structure

Comment: It's in the default package created by spring initialize - package com.xenon.myspringbootapp;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your package structure prevents `BookController` from being component scanned.

When you have your `@SpringBootApplication` defined in package `com.xenon.myspringbootapp`, anything in that package and in nested packages is eligible for component scanning, which will register a bean out of `@(Rest)Controller` and other stereotypes.

Because `BookController` is defined in `book`, it is outside of the component scanned packages and will therefore not be component scanned by your `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

See [the reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html) for more best practices on package structure with Spring Boot applications.

To resolve this, there are two choices to get your class component scanned.

The first (and the way I would recommend) is just to restructure your packages so that the `@SpringBootApplication` class is at the "base" of your application packages. For example, you could move `book.BookController` to be at `com.xenon.myspringbootapp.book.BookController`.

The second is to change the component scanning configuration to include your `book` package. You can do this either on the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation itself:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {
        "com.xenon.myspringbootapp",
        "book"
})
```

Or, define a different `@ComponentScan`. Note that the configuration class annotated with `@ComponentScan` must still be component scanned itself.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringBootAppApplication {

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan("book")
    public static class MyBookComponentScanConfiguration {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootAppApplication.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason 1: Default Spring's component scanning can't fount your `@RestController` component, so you can try to do `@ComponentScan` directly.

Reason 2: You need to specify an endpoint for your `@GetMapping` by using `@RequestMapping`/`@GetMapping("url")` or both of them.

Comment: "You need to specify an endpoint for your @GetMapping" -- That is not needed. No value implies an empty path. That's why it is working in the first screenshot at the root path (`/``).

Comment: And I tried @RequestMapping for Book Class and didn't change anything

Comment: @ComponentScan also didn't work...